# Giving props to other component React Native not working

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to give the data of a certain person to the other component but for some reason this only gives errors.
I tried doing that with the props method as it should but that does not work.

What can be the solution?

Parent:

```
export default function EditFamily({ navigation, props, person, inheritors }) {
  const [shouldShowAdd, setShouldShowAdd] = useState(null);
  const [shouldShowAddChild, setShouldShowAddChild] = useState(null);

  function renderFamily(family, key) {
    return (
      <View key={key} style={styles.family}>
        <View style={styles.inheritors}>
          {family.inheritors.map((inheritor) => {
            return (
              <Add
                key={inheritor.id}
                person={inheritor}
                setShouldShowAdd={setShouldShowAdd}
              />
            );
          })}
        </View>
        {family.children && family.children.length ? (
          <View style={styles.children}>
            {family.children.map((child, index) => renderFamily(child, index))}
          </View>
        ) : null}
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        {shouldShowAdd ? (
          <View style={styles.details}>
            <View style={styles.pressView}>
              <Pressable
                onPress={() => setShouldShowAdd(null)}
                style={styles.pressX}
              >
                <Text>X</Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
            <Pressable>
              <Text>Edit date of {shouldShowAdd.firstname}</Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable
              onPress={() => setShouldShowAddChild(!shouldShowAddChild)}
            >
              <Text>Add child</Text>
            </Pressable>
            {shouldShowAddChild && <AddChild />}
            <Pressable>
              <Text>Add Partner</Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable>
              <Text>Add Parent</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        ) : null}
        <ScrollView>
          <ScrollView horizontal={true}>{renderFamily(data)}</ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Component that gives data to the parent:

```
export default function Add({ person, setShouldShowAdd }) {
  let mijnFoto = 'http://192.168.1.36/CodingApp/assets/' + person.image;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.person}
      onPress={() => setShouldShowAdd(person)}
    >
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        {person.firstname} {person.lastname}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

The component that should for example be able to show the Id of the person that's been clicked:

```
export default function AddChild({ setShouldShowAdd }) {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>hoi id:{person.id}</Text>
   </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: what are the errors you got?

Comment: @darshilsakhiya `person is undefined`

Comment: Have you checked with static data?

Comment: Are you getting the value of `inheritor` in map? please check with `console.log()`

Comment: I get the value of everything from the Add component, but when I want to pass that from the EditFamily to the AddChild component then it errors

Comment: You haven't passed a person to `<AddChild />`

Comment: I thought I had to do that like this: `  <AddChild person={person} setShouldShowAdd={setShouldShowAdd} />` and then call it in my component as `person.id` but that gives the same

Comment: You have to do the same as you have done in `Add` component

Comment: I've been trying that already, but it still does not work

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html.